# payment gateway to deposit a payment to two (or more ) accounts

Tags: payment-gateway, payment

I understand mostpayment gateway just deposit all incoming payment to one account. IS it possible to deposit a payment to two bank accounts (say 90% to one bacnk account and 10% to another business account)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use [Paypal Adaptive Payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro) for this

Comment: Thanks, what about other gateway (something like authorize.net )that payment can be deposited directly to bank account ?

Comment: Unfortunately they don't offer anything like this. Neither does First Data/Linkpoint. Google Checkout *might* but i don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

IANAL but what you are proposing may not even be legal.  Check with your CPA.  Usually, payments come into a current or cash account where they are recorded and the dispersed to 'offsets' or other accounts, again, recorded.  The cash account usually has to be balanced daily.  There are exceptions, usually in the case of third party fees, which are technically a separate transaction, again, your CPA.